# File read reaches end of file unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I'm translating a script from matlab, which reads a file of binary-encoded 32-bit integers and parses them appropriately. I have written the following method that is intended to mimic matlab's fread() function:

```
def readi(f,n):        
    x = zeros(n,int);    
    for i in range(0,n):
        x[i] = struct.unpack('i',f.read(4))[0];
        print x[i];
    return x;
```

I call this function variously with n between 1 and 9 in my script as I parse out the data. My problem is that the script only gets part of the way into the file before I get this error:

```
x[i] = struct.unpack('i',f.read(4))[0];
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

It appears that python thinks I have reached the end of the file. The point in execution where the error occurs is a line in a loop that has already been iterated over several times. In addition, the small portion of the file that has been parsed already matches exactly what my matlab script produces from the exact same file (not a copy). Matlab, however, is able to read a much larger dataset from the file. Does anyone have ideas on why this error is occurring?

Comment: Show us the code where you open the file object. Is it being opened in text mode rather than binary mode?

Comment: One glaring bug here is that you don't define endianess of the input value. Another thing is that the struct module will tell you how many bytes you need, use that info to avoid errors.

Comment: You can sanity check by catching struct.error and printing f.tell(). If it prints the size of your file, you know that the problem isn't in this bit of code.

Comment: Oh, and get rid of those semicolons so that python programmers stop rolling their eyes when they see your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my own testing, whether the file was opened in binary-mode or not (surprisingly) didn't matter. The only thing I can suggest is to make sure you understand the format of the input file *exactly*. So in addition to reading the matlab script, it might be a good idea to look at hex dump of the file where you can see the individual bytes of raw data and be able to verify whether it matches your understanding of the layout of its contents.

Besides all that, you could try the following simplification/optimization of your `readi()` function which does not require the temporary`x`list and reads the bytes of all the integers in the group with one call to`file.read()`:

```
def readi(f, n):
    fmt = '%di' % n
    return struct.unpack(fmt, f.read(struct.calcsize(fmt)))
```

However I don't think it will solve your problem because it should be equivalent to what you already doing, return value-wise anyway (it doesn't print anything like yours).

One final note -- you don't need to end your lines of code with a semicolon. Python isn't like C and several other languages in that respect.

Comment: All good advice. I was able to fix it by opening it as binary. Thanks for simplifying my readi function, too. I was certain there was a one-line approach to it, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Yes, reading the file in binary mode makes sense, which is why I was surprised when it didn't seem to matter in my own (limited) testing. Also note the slight modification/improvement I made to the `readi()` function in my answer.